# Pythonic way of parsing possibly quoted fields

Tags: python, parsing

To do this, I'd normally write a function that pulls one field at a time from the input string, and then loop until the input string is empty.

But there must be a more pythonic way of doing it that splits everything up at once.

Fields in the input string are separated by a space, and fields that contain spaces are enclosed by quotation marks.  Quoted fields do not contain quotation marks.

An real example of this format is a web server's access_log file:

```
216.244.66.234 - - [01/Nov/2019:19:20:07 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)"
```

EDIT:

access_log was a bad choice as an example, as it contains a bracket-delimited field that contains a space.

But since there is a simple solution to my original question (shlex.split()), I'll revise this question to **include processing the bracketed field** too (again with no internal delimiter character).

What I'm looking for is an example of parsing a string into fields in a way other than using a function to pull one token out of the string at a time.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @DanielMesejo, the output format doesn't matter, but let's say the function converts a string into a list of strings.

Comment: What would be the the corresponding list for your example? There is a space before +0000, and is no quoted

Comment: @DanielMesejo, I guess access_log was a bad choice as an example.  But as a matter of interest, how would it be done if the parsing had to handle matched brackets too?  (Again, assume no internal ']' characters.)

Comment: If you mean brackets and comments, I don't think that can be done with shlex.split, although you could replace brackets by comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IUUC, you could use [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
from shlex import split

s = '216.244.66.234 - - [01/Nov/2019:19:20:07 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)"'

for field in split(s):
    print(field)
```

**Output**

```
216.244.66.234
-
-
[01/Nov/2019:19:20:07
+0000]
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
200
67
-
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)
```

Comment: I guess you can't get more pythonic than that:  use a function that someone else has already written.